# Save CSV Output from Data Weave Results as Content File

Tags: dataweave

Thought I'd experiment with the Data Weave functionality, and trying to see if this is the right approach. For a simple POC, I want to run a Contact Query and save it as a CSV file in SFDC.

The script is just:

```
%dw 2.0
input payload application/java
output application/csv
---
payload map {
    fname: $.FirstName,
    lname: $.LastName
}
```

And the anon apex:

```
List<Contact> cons = [select id, lastname, firstname from Contact LIMIT 10];
//String sJSON = JSON.serialize(cons); We might need this to process cross object values I think?
Map<String, Object> args = new Map<String, Object>{ 'payload' => cons };
DataWeave.Script script = DataWeave.Script.createScript('SampleScript1');
DataWeave.Result dwresult = script.execute(args);
String sCSV = (String)dwresult.getValue();

ContentVersion cv = new ContentVersion();
cv.Title = 'Sample SW Results 2';
cv.PathOnClient  = 'Sample SW Results 2.csv';
cv.VersionData = blob.valueOf(sCSV);
insert cv;
```

And this creates a CSV, but you'll see that I am converting the result Object to a String, and then to a Blob.
My question here is - should be able to take the Object output and directly cast it as a Blob for the version data, since DataWeave in apex is subject to various limits, so the less conversion we can do the better I assume? Or is this the way to handle it?

Comment: The `application/csv` output in inherently a string, so will need the conversion to a Blob somewhere in the code. You could pass the `(String)dwresult.getValue()` output direclty into `blob.valueOf` to save the intermediate string variable.

Comment: If anyone else ends up here, also note that you should pass in a string in the other direction e.g. if you want to parse a Content File that is a CSV, convert VersionData to a string and pass that in to the DataWeave script - otherwise, you tend to hit heap issues